# What is the different between LaravelRedis::connection() and Redis::connection() In Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 5.7 `LaravelRedis::connection()` can't return any data but `Redis::connection()` return data successfully, i run this command "composer require predis/predis" before use redis. so is there any difference between those two

Comment: What is `LaravelRedis`? Is this a custom package or an alias you use? It's definitely not part of Laravel itself.